# How to get square brackets with their elements with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
[5][Sport][one]
```

And I want to replace it entirely with the following string:

```
<br />
```

I tried the following regex but it gives me the content of the square brackets `[5,Sport,one]` as a list

```
/[^[\]]+(?=])/g
```

Comment: You want to replace the entire string with `<br />`?  How do you define what gets replaced?  Is it any sequence of consecutive bracket characters?  Or exactly three bracketed sequences that get replaced with one `<br />`?  Your description of what the matching rules are is far too brief.  Please show sample input and sample output and makes sure you include things in the input that you do not want replaced.

Comment: Do you want the three things in []'s to be output separated by <br />'s?

Comment: @jfriend00 their will be just three brackets and I want to replace them with <br />

Comment: [5][Sport][one] I want to put instead of this string <br />.
Note : the text on the brackets is change so that's why I want to use regex

Comment: can you give an actual **example** of what output do you expect?

Comment: I expect <br /> instead of "[5][Sport][one]"

Comment: For your next question, abdel, please read http://sscce.org on how to ask a question so you better help us help you!

Comment: Also, please stop rolling back your edits, because that keeps bumping your question. If this continues, we'll lock the post from editing altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you actually expect, as you do not give what output you want…

So do you mean:

```
js> s = "[5][Sport][one]"
js> s.replace(/\]\[|\[|\]/g,"<br/>")
"<br/>5<br/>Sport<br/>one<br/>"
```

which you can also achieve using the `.match` as I guess you may have tried:

```
js> "<br/>"+s.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g).join("<br/>")+"<br/>"
"<br/>5<br/>Sport<br/>one<br/>"
```

if you do not want the outer `<br/>`, you can just do:

```
js> s.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g).join("<br/>")
"5<br/>Sport<br/>one"
```

EDIT:

given your comment, you want:

```
js> s.replace(/(\[.*\]){3}/g,"<br/>")
"<br/>"
```

which will simply replace *exactly* three occurences of `[…]` with `<br/>`.

N.B.: be careful that `.*` may have side effects with your string, so you may want to use:

```
js> s.replace(/(\[[\d\w]+\]){3}/g,"<br/>")
"<br/>"
```

instead, which matches only digits and letters in the brackets.

Edit #2: as suggested by @aaronm:

```
js> s.replace(/([[^]]]){3}/g,"<br/>")
"<br/>"
```

is even a better solution, as it will matches collated `[…]` strings that contains everything except another `[…]`.

Comment: I want to delete "[5][Sport][one]" and replace it with <br />.
Note : the text on the brackets is change so that's why I want to use regex

Comment: That .* is going to cause no end of grief.  First matching the very simple case it is innefficient and should at a minimum be ".*?". In a larger context it will result in slurping the entire string and then back tracking until it finds a ].  That is if your line/string has multiple sets of 3 braces, it will eat everything between them.  Your second edit example is much better, but using [^]]* would be a more generic solution. s.replace(/(\[[^]]\]){3}/g,"<br/>").

Answer (score 0):

Since regular expressions are greedy, the expression can be quite simple:

```
var s = '[5][Sport][one]';
var re = /\[.*\]/;

console.log(s.replace(re,'<br />')); // <br />
```

Note that HTML does not use XML style empty tags, so instead of `<br />` you should use `<br>`.